# Exponential Distribution - Generate a fairly hefty data set X that is approximately exponentially distributed with μ = 0.7.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, mathematica

I encountered a question in one of the books, which asked to generate a fairly hefty data set X that is approximately exponentially distributed with μ = 0.7.

I can do it for approximately normally distributed, but could not think how to do it for approximately exponentially distributed.

Does anyone know about it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you can generate a Uniform $[0,1]$ random variable $U$, then $-0.7 \log(U)$ has an exponential distribution with $\mu = 0.7$.

Comment: I did it your way, some of my data set elements for exponential distribution came out in the form of "a + i b" complex number. Is it correct ?

Comment: Some of your $U$ values must have been negative, which they should never be for a random variable on $[0,1]$.
The only slight problem that should arise is that the logarithm is not defined at $0$, but with a good pseudo-random number generator the probability of getting exactly $0$ should be very small.

Comment: Can you please provide sample pseudo code?

Comment: Let $u_1, \ldots, u_N$ be a sample of size $N$ from the Uniform[0,1] distribution.  For each $j$ from $1$ to $N$ let $x_j = - 0.7 \ln(u_j)$.